# VirtualBox: add disk image file via the command line

Tags: virtualbox

I am looking for the command line equivalent of the Add Hard Disks feature in the VirtualBox GUI.

Comment: Welcome on this site. Please let us know what you have tried and where you are stuck. The online manual of Virtual box is pretty good...

Comment: If the answer could be found in the online manual, then I wouldn't have asked the question here.

Comment: The online manual is quite clear: [creating a medium](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-createmedium) and [attaching storage](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-storageattach)...